# Creating a custom checkbox using native base checkbox with select all functionality

Tags: typescript, react-native, native-base

I am trying to create a custom checkbox component using Native base checkbox which was pretty straight forward to setup, but I am stuck trying to add a select all checkbox. After some testing with the onChange props I found that the event produced when clicking on the checkbox is just a boolean and not an object. So the object from which the props of the checkbox are made off is not being returned. Has anyone used Native base for a similar purpose. I am new to typescript and native base, and would appreciate some guidance.

Example:

```
const checkList: CheckListType[] = [
  { _id: "one", name: "one", checked: false },
  { _id: "two", name: "two", checked: false },
  { _id: "three", name: "three", checked: false },
  { _id: "four", name: "four", checked: false },
];

const CheckBoxGroupTemplateEx: FC<CheckboxGroupProps> = () => {
  const [list] = useState(checkList);
  const [groupValue, setGroupValue] = useState([]);
  const [selectedBoxes, setSelectedBoxes] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleSelectAllBoxes = () => {
    ????
  };

  const handleSelectBox = (event) => {
   ????
  };

  return (
    <Box alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
      <Text variant="bodyMd">{groupValue.length}</Text>
      <Checkbox.All
        value="select all"
        accessibilityLabel="select all"
        isChecked={selectedBoxes.length === list.length}
        onChange={handleSelectAllBoxes}
      />
      <Checkbox.Group
        onChange={(values) => {
          setGroupValue(values || []);
        }}
      >
        {list.map(({ _id, name, checked }) => (
          <Checkbox
            m={2}
            value={name}
            id={_id}
            accessibilityLabel={name}
            onChange={handleSelectBox}
            isChecked={checked}
          >
            {name}
          </Checkbox>
        ))}
      </Checkbox.Group>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

checkbox group props:

```
export type CheckboxGroupProps = Omit<
  ICheckboxGroupProps,
  "size" | "colorScheme"
>;
```